# How to properly populate/navigate this tree structure using path strings?

Tags: c++, algorithm, xpath, tree, unreal-engine4

### Update:

> Turns out I was needlessly complicating things. For the purposes of a context menu, you really only need an arbitrary tree (with a `Parent`, `FirstChild` and `NextSibling`). The best way to visualize a tree for a context menu is just like any other tree, but branching out horizontally instead of vertically. There's never really any need to be able to walk the tree in 4 different directions (`Up`, `Down`, `Left` and `Right`), because all of the information you need is already there with `Parent`, `FirstChild` and `NextSibling` (all of which is fairly easy to determine if you already have a list of path strings).
>   This thread can safely be closed.

---

I'm not using XPath or any web or DOM-related libraries, but I would like to utilize an XPath-style means of populating the contents of a context menu widget:

```
struct ContextMenuNode
{
    ContextMenuNode* Left; // Parent Menu
    ContextMenuNode* Right; // Sub Menu
    ContextMenuNode* Up; // Previous Sibling
    ContextMenuNode* Down; // Next Sibling
    FString Path; // An XPath-like string
    FString Caption; // Display text of this menu item
}
```

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
// Defined in a class declaration:
TArray<ContextMenuNode*> MenuNodes;

// ...

/* This should create 2 unique nodes ("/File" doesn't exist yet within MenuNodes),
establish Left & Right relationships between them, and
return the newly created "/File/Open" node,
adding both nodes into MenuNodes
*/
auto openFileNode = AddNode("/File/Open");

/* Much like the previous line, this should
create 1 unique node (since "/File" should already exist from the previous call),
Left should be "/File", Up should be "/File/Open".
But also, we need to update THOSE nodes in relation to this node now...
Both "/File/Open" and "/File/Save" are Up/Down siblings with the same Left ("/File")
*/
auto saveFileNode = AddNode("/File/Save");
```

How can this be achieved, or is there simply a better way of going about this?

Useful links for those who are unfamiliar with UE4:

- FString: https://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Core/Containers/FString/index.html
- TArray: http://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Core/Containers/TArray/index.html

Comment: You can achieve it by taking what you wrote down in English, and writing it in code instead...?

Comment: @immibis Wow, never thought of trying that. Thanks! It's almost as if I never needed to come here in the first place! </sarcasm>

Comment: Well, it sounds like you have an idea of what you might need to do. Have you tried doing it? What problems did you run into?

Comment: I'm kind of lost on where to even begin, if recursion is even necessary, or what exactly I should be keeping track of as I attempt to traverse. Using `FString::ParseIntoArray` I can split the path string into an array to count it's depth, but then how do I know what to update (as far as relationships are concerned)?

Comment: So all in all, I guess this comes down to proper tree parsing algorithms... But it's non-binary, quad-directional, and relies on a string to determine it's relationships, which makes it even more confusing

Comment: I suppose one route I haven't tried is using a `TMap<FString, ContextMenuNode*>` (where the key is the path) instead of a `TArray<ContextMenuNode*>`, which could potentially help to ease or eliminate the need for recursive parsing. Or perhaps I could just have the end-user call a separate `populate` method after adding all of the paths, so that relationships are pre-determined?

Comment: Nope, not sure what I was thinking there. A `TMap` is no better than a `TArray` in this scenario. You would still need to parse through all nodes to determine relationships

Comment: I apologise, I forgot to elaborate via examples on what exactly the relationships between `Up`/`Down` and `Left/Right` should be, in this case. Unlike a horizontal menu, a context menu's `Left` & `Right` would correspond to Parent & Submenu (instead of siblings). So perhaps I could've been more specific about this being for a vertical context menu